# Java XMLStreamReader is giving unwanted string

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xmlstreamreader

I have some xml I am reading here it is.

```
<application>
    <client>website</client>
    <register>
        <name>
            <first>Tommy</first>
            <second>Jay</second>
        </name>
        <address>
            <firstLine>line1</firstLine>
            <secondLine>line2</secondLine>
            <city>city1</city>
            <county>county1</county>
            <postcode>YY12 9UY</postcode>
        </address>
    </register>
</application>
```

Anyway when I read it with the xmlStreamReader as below

```
public XMLElementALT getNextElement()
{
    element = new XMLElementALT();
    int event;
    try
    {
        event = reader.next();
    } 
    catch (XMLStreamException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT)
    {
        element.setTag(reader.getLocalName());
    }
    else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS)
    {
        element.setAttribute(reader.getText());
    }
    else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT)
    {
        element.setEndTag(reader.getLocalName());
    }
    else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
        element.setFinished();
    }
    return element;
}
```

This all goes well! However the problem that I have is that after reading the tag  the next event I get is the event XMLStreamConstants.CHARACHTERS and reports that I have the attribute("\n       ") which is the  space between the tag  and the next tag . How can I remove this? I want to have the next event as XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT.I know I could put my XML in all on one line but I like to have the gaps when I input it so that I can see the structure. I also have an xsd to validate against and this validates the xml successfully, is their something in their I can do in the xsd to make it remove the spaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore `CHARACTERS` events that contain only whitespace, either within your `getNextElement` method or by using a filter when you create the reader

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader rawReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(...);
XMLStreamReader filteredReader = factory.createFilteredReader(rawReader,
  new StreamFilter() {
    public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader r) {
      return !r.isWhiteSpace();
    }
  });
```

The `isWhiteSpace` method returns true if the current event is a `CHARACTERS` event consisting entirely of whitespace.  It returns false if it's not a `CHARACTERS` event, or if it is `CHARACTERS` but not all white space.

However, it is important to note that an `XMLStreamReader` is *not* guaranteed to return all the text content of an element in one single `CHARACTERS` event, it is allowed to give you several separate blocks of characters which you must concatenate together yourself.

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate on that with an example regarding not returning all text content of an element?

Comment: @akevit If you have XML like `<ex>foobar</ex>` and the parser is not set to "coalescing" mode then it is allowed to split up the character content and give it to you in several separate events, e.g. you might get `START_ELEMENT`, `CHARACTERS:foo`, `CHARACTERS:bar`, `END_ELEMENT`, instead of just the three events you might expect.  You can force it to combine adjacent runs of characters into one event by setting the `IS_COALESCING` property on the `XMLInputFactory` before you create the reader.

Comment: @akevit I suspect that 99% of the time this won't happen, but it is allowed by the spec so you have to be aware of the possibility (e.g. if a particular parser buffers content internally in a fixed-size buffer and the element content you're looking at happens to span a buffer boundary).

Comment: Ok so to clarify for my sake, relying on `XMLEventReader.peek().isCharacters()` then if true parsing the resulting `.toString()` is not reliable?  This is far from complete I am just experimenting with parsing XML, but this is what I had so far: http://pastebin.com/rS7hTm2u.  I'm not sure if I should be submitting my own question at this point, however I didn't have one until I came across this post.  Given the above, am I setting the property correctly with `factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, true);` ?